# How do I create sticky footers - the other kind of sticky?

Tags: html, css

What I mean is that a footer will always be at the bottom of the browsing window, even if there is a lot of content and normally the footer will be out of view, not the usual "sticky footer" where the footer will always be after the content.

I could achieve this with frames, but how would I do it in a cleaner way with CSS?

Comment: The "usual sticky footer" you describe is not a sticky footer: it's not sticky. It's just a regular footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.the-other-kind-of-sticky-footer { position:fixed; bottom:0; }
```